# jQuery .each() is looping more than once on every element

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, each

In my project I have a table from which I want to remove a specific row by button. Each row shall possess a `name` attribute with a unique index for the representation of the row. This serves as a connection to the server using a ViewModel of MVC4. To transfer to the server it must be numbered consecutively, all names. Say it must have a index. If I will now be remove a row on the client side the indices not automatically disengaged. For this I have now written a couple of jquery functions to revise the indices. However, I have the problem that the method of call each element with a higher index as the deleted one are called more than once. Why is there every element of the  `.each()` method called more than once? Is there a possibility to simplify this code?

Here are the jquery methods:

```
$(function(){
        $('.DeleteButton').click(function () {
            var deletedindex = getIndex(this.name, "DeleteSomething[", "]");
            this.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
            renumberEntry(1, deletedindex);
        });
});
    function renumberEntry(valueToSub, deletedindex) {
        $('#SomethingTableBody > tr > td > .SomethingTableClass').each(function (index, element) {
            element.name = replaceIndexNumber(element.name, "Somethings[", "]", valueToSub, deletedindex);
        });
        $('#SomethingsTableBody > tr > td > .field-validation-valid').each(function (index, element) {
            $(this).attr('data-valmsg-for', replaceIndexNumber($(this).attr('data-valmsg-for'), "Somethings[", "]", valueToSub, deletedindex));
        });
    };
    function replaceIndexNumber(originalText, prefix, suffix, valueToSub, deletedindex) {
        var prefixLength = prefix.length;
        if (originalText.substr(0, prefixLength) == prefix) {
            var index = originalText.indexOf(suffix);
            if (index >= prefixLength) {
                var oldValue = parseInt(originalText.substring(prefixLength, index));
                if (deletedindex < oldValue) {
                    return originalText.substr(0, prefixLength) + (oldValue - valueToSub) + originalText.substr(index);
                }
            }
        }
        return originalText;
    };
    function getIndex(originalText, prefix, suffix) {
        var prefixLength = prefix.length;
        if (originalText.substr(0, prefixLength) == prefix) {
            var index = originalText.indexOf(suffix);
            if (index >= prefixLength) {
                return parseInt(originalText.substring(prefixLength, index));
            }
        }
        return 0;
    };
```

And here's a little detail of the view:

```
                <table id="SomethingsTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>@Html.Label("ID")</th>
                            <th>@Html.Label("Type")</th>
                            <th>@Html.Label("Synonym")</th>
                                                 <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="SomethingsTableBody">
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Somethings)
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Here the editor template:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@model EditSomethingModel

<tr>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.SomethingID, new {@class="SomethingTableClass"</td>
       <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SomethingType.ID, new SelectList(ViewBag.SomethingTypeList, "ID", "Name", Model.SomethingType.ID), new { id = "SomethingTypeList" + @Model.ID + "", Name = "Somethings[" + ViewBag.ListId + "].SomethingType.ID", @class = "SomethingTableClass" })<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Somethings[@ViewBag.ListId].SomethingType.ID" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MainSomethingSynonymId, new SelectList(ViewBag.SomethingSynonymList, "ID", "Name", Model.MainSomethingSynonymId), new { id = "MainSomethingSynonymList" + @Model.ID + "", @class = "SomethingSynonymList SomethingTableClass", Name = "Somethings[" + ViewBag.ListId + "].MainSomethingSynonymId" })<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Somethings[@ViewBag.ListId].MainSomethingSynonymId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
           </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" name="DeleteSomething[@ViewBag.ListId] " value="Delete" class="DeleteButton" id="DeleteSomethingButton_@Model.ID" ></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: "method öffters called?" google übersetzer ftw! :D

Comment: Yes i was a little in hurry so i would like to save you from my bad english. I think this try fails ^^. I overright the text now without google translator. Hope it is understandable now. Sorry.

Comment: Could you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ which has the appropriate MVC generated HTML, would make it considerably easier to see the problem and create a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the Problem. I searched for the error on the false point in the jquery code. 
The problem was, that the dynamiclly generated buttons get everytime i load a new element to the table a new click event. I changed it by unbind all click events from the buttons and give them new events.

Before in my ajax call on success:

```
$('#SomethingTable tr:last').after(html);
                    var table = $('#NeSomethingForm').removeData("validator").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(table);
                    $('.DeleteButton').on('click', function () {
                        var deletedindex = getIndex(this.name, "DeleteSomething[", "]");
                        this.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
                        renumberEntry(1, deletedindex);
                    });
```

and now:

```
$('#SomethingTable tr:last').after(html);
                    var table = $('#NeSomethingForm').removeData("validator").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(table);
                    $(".DeleteButton").unbind("click"); // <-- new line to unbind the events before
                    $('.DeleteButton').on('click', function () {
                        var deletedindex = getIndex(this.name, "DeleteSomething[", "]");
                        this.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
                        renumberEntry(1, deletedindex);
                    });
```